# Can the Heaviside step function be extended for complex values?

Tags: complex-analysis

Title says it all. In order to apply Cauchy's theorem I need a to extend the step function. So, can the Heaviside step function be extended for complex values, such that it is holomorphic except at the origin?

Comment: Hint: What would the identity theorem imply?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no holomorphic function on $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{0 \}$ agreeing with the Heaviside step function on $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{ 0 \}$. This can be seen in several ways, the easiest is perhaps to use that zeros of holomorphic functions are isolated (unless the function is the zero function).