fourier transform $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-(x+ia)^2}}$
I am trying to evaluate the Fourier Transform
$$
f(z)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx \exp(-ixz)\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-(x+ia)^2}}\quad \mbox{where}\ a > 0
$$
Does anyone have any clues/hints at obtaining an analytical solution?

Following the comments, on using $y=x+ia$,
$$
f(z)=\exp(-az)\int_{-\infty+ia}^{\infty+ia} dy \exp(-iyz)\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-y^2}}=\exp(-az) H_0^{(1)}(z)
$$
I expect $f(z)$ to be non-zero only for $z>0$ based on the physical problem from which this integral is derived. It is not obvious to me how this feature shows up explicitly. Probably the shift $y = x + ia$ ?.


You may want to look into Bessel functions, especially $J_0$, and shift the integration variable

On using $y=x+ia$, $f(z)=\exp(-az) \int_{-\infty}^\infty dy \exp(-iyz)/\sqrt{1-y^2}$. The expected behaviour (from the underlying physics problem) is that $f(z)$ is non-zero only for $z>0$. How is this obvious from this result?

depending on the sign of $z$, you can close the contour around a branch cut along $[-1,1]$. Are you familiar with Hankel contours?

I am not aware of it. I can look it up though.

@LPZ It seems for $z>0$, we have a semicircular contour on the lower half plane, which can be shrunk to the dogbone contour around the branch cut, yielding your result. But, the integral over the semicircular arc at infinity is troublesome right? since the integrand decays only as 1/x...

You need to use Jordan's lemma, giving you a faster exponential decay. It's due to the exponential that you conveniently choose the semicircular contour on the lower half plane.

OK, so for every $z$, except for $z=0$ exactly, this works.

Let $f(z)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-z^2}}$
Non-unitary Fourier Transform of $f(x)$:
$$\mathcal{F}_x[(\theta(x+1)-\theta(x-1))\cdot f(x)](z)=\int_{-1}^1 f(x)\cdot e^ {-i x z} \, dx=\pi\cdot J_0(|z|)$$
$$\mathcal{F}_x[f(x+ i a)](z)=\mathcal{F}_x[\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-(x+i a)^2}}](z)=2 \theta(\Re(z))\cdot e^{-a z}\cdot \pi J_0(|z|),\quad a>0$$
Verify with convolution
$$g(x)=\mathcal{F}_z^{-1}[2 \theta(\Re(z))\cdot e^{-a z}](x)=\frac{1}{\pi (a-i x)}$$
$$(f*g)(x)=\int_{-1 }^{+1} f(\xi)\cdot g(x-\xi ) \, d\xi=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{(a-i x)^2}} (a-i x)}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-(x+i a)^2}},\quad a>0$$
HINT: $\theta(x)$ is the Heaviside theta function.

$f(x+ i a)$ is undefined, as Heaviside function is only defined for real arguments. See: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1797774/can-the-heaviside-step-function-be-extended-for-complex-values. I don't understand the step where you equate $f(x+i a)$ to  $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-(x+ia)^2}}$. Can you please explain? Alternately (wihtout invoking heaviside), your definition of $f(x)$ has the condition $-1 \lt x \lt 1$. I am unclear about the equivalent for a complex variable. Surely $-1 \lt (x+i a) \lt 1$ is not correct in the context of a complex variable. Please define $f(x)$ for complex case.

Modifications done. But doesn't change the result.

I did not get why you integrated only in the range (-1,1)

Perhaps this helps: MSE_Q4933779

Ok, I understood how the integral contour is deformed into the "dogbone" contour around the branch chosen to be [-1,1]. But how does the heaviside step naturally show up? It seems to me that regardless of the sign of z, we end up with the same dogbone contour.

Maybe someone else can answer your questions on the topic better.
Seems to be an endless story.
